# Integerating sharepoint 2010 with yammer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, yammer

i am currently developing a share point site with yammer web part and when i try to do it.I am stuck up with a issue.

what i tried ::

Siteactions->Edit page -> Insert->Webpart->Yammer apps

After which i get a error like this

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' at Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.SPUserProfileManager.GetProfile(String accountName, SPSite site) at Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.YammerSharePointContentStore.GetUserEmail() at Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.DefaultYammerSettingsManager.EnsureYammerSession(String networkId) at Yammer.SharePoint.WebParts.YammerAppsWebPart.CreateChildControls()

I installed all pre requisites as given the yammer for share point Documentation.

Is there any dll file missing or anyother issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is I haven't deployed the Yammer for sharepoint wsp correctly.

Instead I tried http://success.yammer.com/integrations/sharepoint/ this link in which select the online option

INSTALLATION::

1 . Download the web part from success.yammer.com.

From Site Actions, click Site Settings.
From Galleries, click Solutions.
Click Library.
Click Solutions.
Click Upload.
Browse to the Yammer for SharePoint Online wsp file.
Click Activate.
after which you can easily add web part for yammer

Pre Requisites:: your service account need to configured with yammer credentials hope this would help